# sh script that change the title of a MATE terminal tab [tcsh]

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, tcsh

Im trying to understand how to write a shell script that changes the shell tab title. Is there a certain variable that controls it?

Any way the end goal this:

```
changeTitle.sh newTitle
```

Thanks,

Comment: `the shell tab title` What application is showing you "the shell tab title"?

Comment: No need of any external app, its just appear above each tab of the terminal.

Comment: `its just appear above each tab of the terminal` In what terminal? What program is doing the "just appear"? There are endless [terminal emulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terminal_emulators) - which one are you using?

Comment: MATE Terminal  a fork of GNOME Terminal (so it's written here https://mate-desktop.org) @KamilCuk